# find file upload path in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Can any body explain this code? i am confused please guide me and explain this code easy wording  in JSP language .Thanks

```
if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ) {
              file = new File( filePath + 
              fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
           } else {
              file = new File( filePath + 
              fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
           }
           fi.write( file ) ;
           out.println("<h3>Uploaded Filename:</h3> "+fileName);
        }
     }
```

Comment: You have not specified which specific part you are confused at. Also, full code should have been provided indicating variables - `fileName`, `filePath ` & `fi`. Code has less to do with JSP and more to do with Core Java.

Comment: what means of this condtion if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ) and .substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ; and s.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;

Answer (score 1):

In java file path can be described by `\\`.

For example: `String path = "D:\\folder1\\folder2\\filename.type"`

`lastIndexOf("\\")` will return the last position value of `\\` from your `file name`.

The variable `file` will be assigned the `path` from which the file is going to be uploaded in the java program from your disk.

The `if` and `else` blocks check the file path is correct and it assigned the variable `path`.

Finally `write` method uploads the file from specified path.

Answer (score 1):

First refer documentation of methods - `lastIndexOf`and `substring` [lastIndexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) & [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int))  to understand what these methods do.

Also note that we use double slashes in code due to `\` being escape character so `\\` means single slash `\`

If you apply, `lastIndexOf("\\")` , you might get either value `-1` or  `>=0` . `-1` value would mean that `\`  is not present in that String and value `>=0` means that it is present.

In this below if part, you simply determine if `\` is there in `fileName` , if it is there - take only last portion and append with `filePath`  so for a `fileName` with value like `abc\test.txt`  you are extracting only `\test.txt` and appending to `filePath`.

```
if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ) {
              file = new File( filePath + 
              fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
}
```

Then , in `else` part,  we already know that `\` is not present in so code is unnecessarily doing - `fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)` - this will always be zero.

```
else {
              file = new File( filePath + 
              fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
           }
```

So code can simply be written as ,

`else{
file = new File( filePath +fileName)}`

line - `new File(....)` creates a `File` object that is where stream contents get written to.

On SO, these kind of questions don't get answered but I answered since your profile says that you are a student.

Secondly, I can't comment if that code is correct or incorrect, I simply explained what that code is doing.